# Should I map properties that will not be used in any query?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have some fields that I need in the _source response, but I will never use them in any filter or aggregation. Does it make sense to remove them from the mapping to save memory? Considering that I am using dynamic: false, they won't be mapped when I reindex them, but they will still be present in the _source.

For me, this makes sense, but I dont't know if this can be considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need those fields in the _source but you're not using them in your queries or aggregations, you can simply add [`index: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) in your mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "field": {
               "type": "keyword",
               "index": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For `object` fields, you can add [`"enabled": false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) instead

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "session": {
               "type": "object",
               "enabled": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.
I'm currently using a 6.x version. Do you know if this approach exists in this version?

Comment: Yes, it's also working in 6.x